# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: for map(int, list) in Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, valueerror

I am trying to learn the functionality of map() in python

Now when i do this,

```
bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1']
ports = map(int, bits)
#The below line is for the next iteration, where plus_net can be considered a counter
ports = [p+_plusnet for p in ports]
```

Now bits is a list here, And when I try to map() to iterate along ports, I get the error,

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'and'

Not sure how to handle this.
Suggestions?
Thanks !

Comment: What do you think `something = int("and")` achieve? `map` applies the `int` function to all elements of your list. If there are non-ints in it, you need to catch the resulting error and handle it.

Comment: How do you _want_ to handle this? Throw away the `"and"`? Return a placeholder value?

Comment: There are tons of way to handle, including ignoring the element, replacing the result with a default, or entirely eliminating it from the input. *You* must define what the desired operation is; we can help you code it but not select it.

Comment: I am going to append it to a gates[] array [gates.append((gate, ports))], so my final gates[] will have the value like this [('and', [2, 3, 1])]

Answer (score 2):

```
bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1']
ports = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in bits]
#OP request, get tuple
ports = ((ports[0], [port for port in ports[1:]]))
```

Use list comprehension to check is your list element is eligible for `int` type. If so do `int()`, if not don't.

Alternatively, remove non-eligible elements:

```
bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1']
ports = [int(s) for s in bits if s.isdigit()]  
#The below line is for the next iteration, where plus_net can be considered a counter
ports = [p+_plusnet for p in ports]
```

Comment: ports = [int(s) if s.isdigit() for s in bits]
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax...Getting this errror

Comment: And for the first logic you will be getting an error at ports = [p+_plusnet for p in ports]
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Yes I corrected. For the second part of your comment, that's your logic to question. You can not concatenate str and int objects ;). What do you want?

Comment: am going to append it to a gates[] array [gates.append((gate, ports))], so my final gates[] will have the value like this [('and', [2, 3, 1])]

Comment: Ok, will you have a list of lists for bits or will you ever be using simple list such as [str, int...]. Said differently, is your tuple element in gates always str index 0 and list of integer coming next from ports?

Answer (score 2):

```
bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1']

def myint(a):
    if a.isdigit():
        return int(a)
    else:
        return 0
ports = map(myint, bits)
ports = [p+_plusnet for p in ports]
```

if you want to replace string litral

Comment: In this case I will get an extra 0 right ? my result would be  [('and', [0, 2, 3, 1])]

Comment: basically i want to remove the 'and' and return only [2,3,1]

Answer (score 0):

map(fun, iterable) => fun will be applied on each element of iterable.
And with this logic.

map(int bits)
int('and') will throw invalid literal for int() with base 10 because you can't convert alphabet literal to int directly.

Comment: bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1']

def myint(a):
    if a.isdigit():
        return int(a)
    else:
        return 0
ports = map(myint, bits)
ports = [p+_plusnet for p in ports]

Answer (score -1):

```
# Lets do a lambda function to solve the problem and add a condition
# if there is a int value in bits list it will be added too

bits    = ['and', '2', '3', '1']    
intplus = lambda i,p: \
              (isinstance(i,str) and i.isdigit() and int(i)+p) or \
              (isinstance(i,int) and i+p) or i
ports   = [ intplus(p, _plusnet) for p in bits ]

# bits = ['and', '2', '3', '1', 5] will work too and 5 will be added
```